# How to cast returned value of XPathEvaluate?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I”m trying to cast the returned value of XPathEvaluate method to IEnumerable.
This code doesnt work:
`var elements = (IEnumerable<XObject>) doc.XPathEvaluate(myXpath);`

And This approach works fine:
`var elements = ((IEnumerable<object>) doc.XPathEvaluate(myXpath)).Cast<XObject>();`

Could someone please explain me the difference? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`XPathEvaluate` returns `EvaluateIterator` behind the object.

It cannot be casted directly to `IEnumerable<XObject>`.

The `Cast` method runs through this iterator and returns the converted `IEnumerable<XObject>` sequences.

Comment: „It cannot be casted directly to IEnumerable„

So why I am able to cast the EvaluateIterator directly to the IEnumerable<object> (2nd example from my question) or just IEnumerable?

Comment: @rkamx - [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance)

Comment: @rkamx - I can't see your xpath, so I don't know exactly which nodes are being returned. I assume that there is `XElement`.

Comment: Thanks, It looks like i mistook the contravariance for the covariance ;)
In the first example i was trying to cast IEnumerable<object> (Returned by EvaluateIterator under the hood) to the IEnumerable<XObject> and it is not possible because IEnumerable<out T> is covariant (so i can not cast object to XObject directly). Am i right?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [extension method XPathEvaluate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xpath.extensions.xpathevaluate?view=netcore-3.1), returns this method an `object`, which is either a bool, a double, a string, or an `IEnumerable`.

Luckily, if we have an IEnumerable sequence of similar objects we can convert it to an `IEnumerable<XObject>`.

If you are certain that every element in the enumerable sequence is an XObject, you can use `Enumerable.Cast<XObject>()`. If you think that some object might be of another type and you want to ignore the other types, use `Enumeable.OfType<XObject>`

```
object evaluatedDocument = doc.XPathEvaluate(myXpath);
if (evaluatedDocument is IEnumerable enumerableSequence)
{
    // the returned object implements IEnumerable
    IEnumerable<XObject> result = enumerableSequence.Cast<XObject>();

    // or:
    IEnumerable<XObject> result = enumerableSequence.OfType<XObject>();
}
```